# How to get wide character fonts on KDE?

Tags: kde

I have to help a person, using KDE 4.9.3, and I'm not an expert on KDE.
He has not a good sight, so I grew up the character fonts on the system (from the KDE configuration tool), so he is satisfied for the appearance of Dolphin or the desktop.

But what's about Gimp, LibreOffice or Firefox, the character fonts still undersized ! Is there a way to correct that ?

Comment: Hi, did you already look into the KDE Accessibility tools? http://community.kde.org/Accessibility

Answer (score 1):

Try to correct it under system settings -> Appearance -> Font -> Force fonts DPI with 100 for example [image] and restart kde with

```
sudo service sddm restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could install the Gnome Tweak Tool and set font sizes there, as it could be that the applications you mention are made with GTK instead of QT, and thats why the font sizes don't change. But if you change some settings in the Gnome Tweak Tool, it might help. Just a suggestion.

Comment: not working :/ I tried with the System Settings -> Application Appearance -> GTK+ Appearance, but there is no change ... I tried with Gnome-Tweak-Tool, same thing ... I rebooted the PC, the same result !